# $_POST empty when using $.post

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my problem:
I want to make a database search using PHP form. I have my form and I want it to work even if there are some empty fields (as like more fields u fill, the more specific answer u get). I am using Jquery to first get values from my form and then send it by $.post to my actual php file which connects with database and do the search. I am simply giving empty fields some specific value which is recognized in my php file as 'empty' field so i can make a proper sql query. The problem is I find my $_post variables empty, even though variables in Jquesry script are set properly. I am using this method in other cases and it works fine. I have no idea if this matter but I am loading my form inside my main div using Jquery as well. The alert(data) function does its job: in prompt window i can see my results of search but reloading profile.php gives me nothing. Here is my code:

form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/admin.js"></script>
<form id="form_admin">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="180">
        <p style="line-height: 2cm; ">
            <tr>
                <td width="50" class="label1">Imię:</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="imie" type="text" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50" class="label1">Nazwisko:</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="nazwisko" type="text" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50" class="label1">Numer telefonu:</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="telefon" type="text" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" id="register" value="Pokaż!">
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </p>
    </table>
</form>
```

admin.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").click(function () {
        if ($("#imie").val() != "") {
            var imie = $("#imie").val();
        } else {
            var imie = 'nic';
        }
        if ($("#nazwisko").val() != "") {
            var nazwisko = $("#nazwisko").val();
        } else {
            var nazwisko = 'nic';
        }
        if ($("#telefon").val() != "") {
            var telefon = $("#telefon").val();
        } else {
            var telefon = 'nic';
        }
        $.post("profile.php", {
            name: imie,
            surname: nazwisko,
            telephone: telefon
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        $("#main").load('profile.php');
    });
});
```

profile.php

```
<? php
include('config.php');#logging into database
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['telephone'])) {
    $IMIE = $_POST['name'];
    $NAZWISKO = $_POST['surname'];
    $TELEFON = $_POST['telephone'];#then my sql queries go...
    while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        echo 'ORDER_ID zamówienia: '.$user['ORDERINFO_ID'];
        echo 'DATA zamówienia: '.$user['DATE_PLACED'];
    }
    while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)) {
        echo 'SUBORDER_ID: '.$user['SUBITEM_ID'];
        echo 'Ilość: '.$user['QUANTITY'];
        echo 'Koszt zamówienia: '.$user['COST'];
    }
} else {
    echo "$_POST variables aren't set";
}
?>
```

Edit:
I have installed Firebug and checked POST profile.php after submitted data and it contains all variables as expected.

Comment: For the love of god please format your code!

Comment: remove value="" from all input elements. its post the empty value.

Comment: is your `profile.php` in the same directory as your javascript?

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically are the values lost?  Do the variables contain what you expect when constructing the object in JavaScript?  Are they sent in the request according to your browser's debugging tools?  Don't just dump your code here, *debug it*.

Comment: @sircapsalot it is not, i have scripts in my scripts directory while all the php files are outside of it. I have checked my name, surname and telephone variables inside javascript and php file returns "$_POST variables aren't set" which implies isset function returns false.

Comment: the only thing that possibly makes sense currently, is your config.php file must be modifying the POST. do a print_r or var_dump before the include config

Comment: @AlanAsher print_r shows there is an Array of all my variables, as I expect them to.

Comment: Ok. then if you move the print statement after the config.. what do you see?

Comment: @AlanAsher it strange. I get an array with 3 elements inside on prompt window (i guess its alert(data) function) but when loading profile.php i get empty array and my "#_POST variables aren't set" error.
Edit: actually even before my config incude when loading profile.php i get empty array while alert(data) gives 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your $.post function to:

```
$.post("profile.php", {
        data: "&name=" + imie + "&surname=" + nazwisko + "&telephone=" + telefon
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: stil doesn't work. Even alert(data) doesn't show query results anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs do not have any name

for example:

```
<input id="imie" type="text" value="" name="imie">
```

Comment: I dont think i need them, im not using form itself for sending data, but im retriving values from input boxes and using $.post to put them into $_POST variable. I have tried adding names to all inputs and stil nothing changes.

Comment: he doesn't need them when sending form data via $.post();